For which real numbers does the equation: $4^x + 2^{x+1} = a$ have a real solution?
I have made some progress, but can't seem to figure out what the last step should be.
I did the following steps:
$$4^x + 2^{x+1} = a$$
$$2^{2x} + 2^{x+1} = a$$
By substitution: $2^x = t$
$$t^2 = 2^{2x}$$
$$t^2 + 2t - a = 0$$
$$t = -1 \pm \sqrt{1+a}$$
$$t_1 = -1 + \sqrt{1+a}$$
$$t_2 = -1 - \sqrt{1+a}$$
For real solutions: $\sqrt{1+a} \geq 0 \Rightarrow a \geq -1$
$$2^x = -1 + \sqrt{1+a}$$
$$x = \frac{\ln({\sqrt{1+a}-1})}{\ln{2}}$$
I don't understand how to proceed from here.

You have to just find the range of $4^{x}+2^{x+1}$. This function is continuous and increasing and the range is $(0,\infty)$. Your method also shows that there is a  solution for every $a>0$.

Maybe I have tunnel vision because I can't even understand how to go about doing that. Could you write it down?

The question is: "For which $a$ do we have a solution?" You have found a solution for any $a$ for which the RHS of $$x = \frac{\ln({-1+\sqrt{1+a}})}{\ln{2}}$$ is defined. You know the domains of logarithm and square root, so to finish up you need to solve the system of inequalities \begin{align}
-1+\sqrt{1+a} &> 0\\
1+ a &\geq 0.
\end{align}
The first inequality is satisfied if and only if $a > 0$ and the second is satisfied if and only if $a \geq -1$. Intersection gives us $a \in \langle 0,\infty\rangle$.

Since $2^{x} > 0$, the following relations must hold:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
a\geq -1\\\\
-1 + \sqrt{1 + a} > 0
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
a\geq -1\\\\
\sqrt{1 + a} > 1
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
a\geq - 1\\\\
a > 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Hence $a\in(0,+\infty)$.

I can't upvote this since I still don't have reputation points, but in any case, thanks! This made it clear.

@aconfusedtortoise you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

As geetha190krm said in the comments, you don't need to solve for $x$. It is enough to find the range of the function $$f(x)=4^x+2^{x+1}.$$
First of all,
$f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R.$ Secondly, $$f'(x)=4^x\ln4+2^{x+1}\ln2>0$$ for all $x\in\Bbb R.$ Therefore, $f(x)$ is an increasing function on $\Bbb R$. Finally,
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$
tell us that the range of $f(x)$ is $\Bbb R^+=(0,\infty)$ because $f(x)$ is continuous. So,
$$4^x+2^{x+1}=a$$ has a "unique" solution if $a>0$.

Maybe this solution is not well come and not necessary for OP as it is already said in the comments.

You don't need to solve anything just to prove a solution exists.
$4^x+2^{x+1}$ is clearly continuous and as $x \to -\infty$ we have $4^x+2^{x+1}\to 0$ and as $x\to \infty$ we have $4^x + 2^{x+1}\to \infty$ so by the intermediate value thereom for all $a \in (0,\infty)$ we have $4^x + 2^{x+1}=a$ has a solution.
We are under no obligation to express it.
.... more detail ....
Let $0< a$.  Let $w < \min (\log_4 (\frac 12a),\log_2 (\frac 12a) -1)$ and $v > \max (\log_4 (\frac 12a),\log_2 (\frac 12a) -1)$.  Then $4^w + 2^{w-1} < 4^{\min (\log_4 (\frac 12a),\log_2 (\frac 12a) -1)} + 2^{\min (\log_4 (\frac 12a),\log_2 (\frac 12a) -1)+1} \le 4^{\log_4(\frac 12a)}+2^{\log_2(\frac 12 a)-1+1}=\frac 12a + \frac 12 a=a$.
By the exact same logic $4^v + 2^{v+1} > a$.  THus by the intermediate value theorem there must be an $x$ with $w < x < v$ were $4^x + 2^{x+1} = a$.
All the remains to show is that if $a \le 0$ there is not solution.  But that's trivial as $4^x + 2^{x+1} > 0$ for all real $x$.
